# Weak entity on mysql with no primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship

I have a question about transfering a weak entity from an e-r model to sql tables.
Specifically i am using mysql.

Lets say i have the table hotels in which i have primary key id for each hotel, named id.

Then i want to create a table for rooms. A room is considered weak entity because it cannot be identified without refering to a hotel and because it cannot exist without a hotel.

So lets say that rooms contain columns with data and two other columns.
First column is a foreign key to hotel id and a second column which is a room number.

Note than many rooms can have the same number but no room in the same hotel can have the same number. So this is a way to identify a specific room.

How can i put this into a table?
I cannot declare the number as unique because its not unique, i cannot declare it as a primary key either for the same reason. So am i creating a table without primary key?

Also, the foreign key "hotel_id" is a unique key since it is a primary key in hotels table.
I suppose i won't having problems using many rooms with the same foreign key.

To sum up.
My question is how to create the table rooms, is there any way to automatically identify each room except the obvious (identifying the room by selecting a room with specific number and hotel_id)?.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The primary key in the Rooms table is composed of two columns (HotelID, RoomNumber).  That combination must be unique for your data model to operate correctly.

Comment: Lets say that a room with number 5 in hotel 1 exists. I want when i try to add a room with number 5 in hotel 2 to be successful, but when i try to add a room with number 5 in hotel 1 to be unsuccessful. How to tell the sql to do this?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE rooms ADD PRIMARY KEY (hotel_id, room_number)`.  That is all you need to do.  You can use the same `room_number` with different `hotel_id`s, but never twice with the same `hotel_id`.

Comment: +1. @tchar: A UNIQUE constraint on the combination of the two columns is sufficient.   `UNIQUE INDEX ... ON  (hotel_id, room_number)`. And defining the combination of columns as the `PRIMARY KEY` is one way to achieve that. But it can also be achieved by creating a secondary index.

Answer (score 0):

You create a table `rooms` with an `id` column as primary key. This table has also the columns `hotel_id` (FK to `hotels`) and `room_number`. You define an unique index over `(hotel_id, room_number)`.

That's all ;)

Comment: In such a design, there's no obvious reason to create the `id` column `rooms`.  (hotel_id, room_number) is fine as the PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: If i define room_number as unique i wont be able to insert another room with the same number. I want to be able to insert a room with the same number and different hotel....

Comment: You define **one** index over **two** columns! Not two indices. This makes a huge difference.

Comment: @LarryLustig It's not needed, but it eases some things.

Comment: While it can ease some things it can also complicate other things -- and there's a performance penalty since you're doubling the indexing work the database has to do.  In this case in particular it's unlikely that the user interface will be presenting rooms side-by-side from different hotels so the problem of having to represent a compound primary key through something like an HTML id field is not likely to occur.

Comment: I don't see a situation where it could complicate things? Yes, there is a minor performance penalty, but until now I have not heard of a database server which died out of an additional integer column.

Comment: I want to avoid creating an extra column just for the primary key because the entity room is considered to be weak according to the e-r diagram i created (i want to follow the e-r diagram i created). Adding hotel_id and room_no as a primary key (or unique) is a good idea i think. Anyways, thanks for your time and your helpful advice. Should i answer my question now that it is answered?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answers, yes. This does not prohibit further answers, so even if you do it now, someone with another better answer, who comes later, still has the chance to give this answer.